# user as |user| not working in Ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

When I'm doing `{{#each model as |user|}}` it works but when I'm doing `{{#each user as |user|}}`, it doesn't show anything.

I need `users` since it will be in a nested route.

This works:

```
{{#each model as |user|}}
  {{user.name}}
  {{user.email}}
{{else}}
    Sorry, nobody is here.
{{/each}}
```

But this doesn't:

```
{{#each users as |user|}}
  {{user.name}}
  {{user.email}}
{{else}}
    Sorry, nobody is here.
{{/each}}
```

I want to pass a `{{#link-to 'users.user' class="nav-link"}}Users{{/link-to}}` helper. So, I need `{{#each users as |user|}}`.

Any help will be highly solicited.

Comment: Use setupController hook in route to set model to users...or you can model property itself...In #each block you can try this {{#link-to user class="nav-link"}}Users{{/link-to}}.

Comment: Please post tour router file. What is the model in your case and what should be users. The reason why you cannot use each users since users is not passed to template. Please post so I can give you answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{{#each model as |user|}} //this works because default setupController() will set model property
```

You can try using the below one

```
{{#each model as |user|}}
 {{#link-to user class="nav-link"}}Users{{/link-to}}
{{/each}}
```

If you would like to access model using users then you need to add below code in setupController hook of users route.

```
setupController(controller,model){
 this._super(controller, model);
 controller.set('users', model);
}
```